# How to timeout established curl connection apart from max-time

Tags: curl, libcurl

Want to terminate connection if there is no response from server after connecting without using -max-time.

Why not max-time is because I also download 10GB file in my server and it takes 10 min. so if I'm downloading 1Mb file and connection is stalled then is some timeout should terminate connection rather than waiting for max-time?

Answer (score 0):

You might like

```
 -Y, --speed-limit <speed>
     If  a  download is slower than this given speed (in bytes per second) for speed-time
     seconds it gets aborted. speed-time is set with -y, --speed-time and is  30  if  not
     set.

 -y, --speed-time <seconds>
     If a download is slower than speed-limit bytes per second during a speed-time
     period, the download gets aborted. If speed-time is used, the  default speed-limit
      will be 1 unless set with -Y, --speed-limit.
```